# Laravel Passport callback route returns null

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-passport

I am learning Laravel Passport and developing an OAuth2 server. After creating a client I made the following call to get the authorization code

```
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    $request->session()->put('state', $state = Str::random(40));

    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => <Client_Id>,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://<Consumer_App_URL>/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
        'state' => $state,
    ]);

    return redirect('http://<OAuth2_Server_URL>/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
```

The call works as expected and I got the authorization code, however when redirecting to the callback route which is defined like so

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $state = $request->session()->pull('state');

    throw_unless(
        strlen($state) > 0 && $state === $request->state,
        InvalidArgumentException::class
    );

    $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://<OAuth2_Server_URL>/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => <Client_Id>,
        'client_secret' => '<Cient_Secret>',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://consumer/callback',
        'code' => $request->code,
    ]);

    return $response->json();
});
```

It didn't work, the response instance is just null. I can't figure out what might be the issue.

Comment: try to look for more info about the error in the laravel/apache log file

Comment: So when inspecting the request from browser it shows a status of 200, but when calling $request->status() it shows error 500

Comment: OK, after inspecting the laravel logs again, it seems like it tries to connect to my 'consumer app' database and select from 'oauth_clients' table although there is no table like that in my consumer. I can't understand why it behaves like this

Comment: Here is the exact log record
[2020-12-14 14:50:01] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'consumer.oauth_clients' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `oauth_clients` where `id` = 3 limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'consumer.oauth_clients' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `oauth_clients` where `id` = 3 limit 1) at C:\\laragon\\www\\passport-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:671)

Comment: have you ran the migration ?

Comment: Yes in server and consumer

Comment: have you tried to look into what you receive in $request, try to add `$response->throw();` after `$response`, and put it in try catch block and try to catch `Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException` exception, in the RequestException catch block log the error using `$e->getMessage(), if($e->hasResponse(){$e->getResponse() }`

Comment: the request has the code and state 'which is what expected I think?' Trying to throw the exception just returns HTTP request returned " status code 500: <!doctype html> <html class="theme-light"> <!-- Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view (truncated...) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem, I just have to run `php artisan config:cache` . [[reference]](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/76#issuecomment-247818083)

Comment: To me this didn't work. I had some events of [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#events) on `EventServiceProvider` that got an error.